# Change css when keypad pop ups on phone screen

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am making login page for my android app and initially the login and password fields are placed in center of the screen. When I tap on the screen, the keypad pops up and hides parts of the fields which I don't want. How can I change the position of the login block when the keyboard pops up? JavaScript/jQuery solutions are fine.

Comment: Show your code that you tried

Comment: thanks for ur comment. I am developing my app using phonegap and searched a lot for keypad pop event or anything like but unfortunately could nt find anything useful :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to attach to an event specifically related to showing the keyboard.

As such, I'd suggest the best approach is to call a function on focus.
Without knowing the structure of your page I can't give you any specific code, but here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#login').focus(function(){
      //reduce the top margin when the text box is focussed.
      $(this).css('margin-top', '-100px');
   })
   .blur(function(){
      //revert the change.
      $(this).css('margin-top', '');
   });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...it gave me a startup. I have pasted my code @ link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899145/getting-logcat-message-ignore-this-event-while-code-works-correctly-for-browser please check once..thanks again

Comment: if it helped, then vote up/accept my answer please :)
Also, it's better to edit a current question than to create a new one if the subject is still the same.

Comment: i just did :-) and about posting new question I tried to post my code in the comment but failed to paste my code...God knows how it works :-(