# getting logcat message ignore this event while code works correctly for browser

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I have a login form in my phone app and in that I need to initially place my form elements in center of the screen and later when some one tries to enter inputs to login name or password the input block get shifted upwards so that it does not get hidden by the keypad. Though my code works fine in browser, in phonegap I get ignore this event. Please guide

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>daDrive - Login</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/code/util.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/code/login.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/code/register.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/code/account.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/code/home.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/code/constants.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../css/common.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.min.css" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jqm-docs.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input").focus(function(){
                if(flag==0){
                    flag=1;
                    $("#loginPass_txtboxes").animate({"margin-top": "-=30%"}, "slow");
                }
            });
            document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
                if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase()!="input" && flag==1){
                    flag=0;
                    $("#loginPass_txtboxes").animate({"margin-top": "+=30%"}, "slow");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page_id">
        <div id="loginPageLogo" style="margin-top:3%;">
            <center><img src="../images/logo_dadrive.png"/></center>
        </div>            
        <div data-role="content" id="main_page" style="padding:0 !important;">      
            <div id="login_middle_content">
                <div id="loginPass_txtboxes" style="width: 60%; margin-left: 20%; margin-top:35%" onblur="shiftDown()">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label" >
                        <label for="LoginId">Login ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="LoginId" id="LoginId"  value="" placeholder="Login Id" data-mini="true"/>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" data-mini="true"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div align="center">
                    <a href="javascript:login();" data-role="button"  data-theme="b" id ="button_size">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div><!--middle-->     
        </div>
    </div><!--page -->
</body>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that var flag has been defined in one of the impoted script files, so no error is due to that

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333689/android-softkeyboarddetect-ignore-this-event-what-does-it-mean) which also provides some details for handy events you might like.

Comment: i had seen that link before but could not get any solution for my problem